# Adding labels to groups in d3 force layout

Tags: d3.js, webcola

Is there a way to add labels to the groups for the d3-cola force layout example [here](http://ialab.it.monash.edu/webcola/examples/smallworldwithgroups.html)

I have added tooltips:

```
var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
    .data(groups)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .classed("group", true)
    .attr("rx",20)
    .attr("ry",20)
    .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); })
    .call(cola.drag);

group.append("title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.id; });
```

I tried adding this part:

```
var groupText = svg.selectAll(".group")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "link-label")
    .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "Black")
    .style("font", "normal 9px Arial")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return (d.id);
    });
```

And then in the tick function:

```
groupText
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return ((d.bounds.x + d.bounds.width())/2);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return ((d.bounds.y + d.bounds.height())/2);
    });
```

But it doesn't show up.

Comment: a rect can't have a text subtag. Append a new text tag based on the attributes or datum of the rect to the svg with a `groupText.each()`

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for the advice! I added the following, the tooltip works but the text, i.e. d.id does not show up:

Comment: var group = svg.selectAll(".group")
              .data(groups)
                .enter().append("g")
                .append("rect")
                .classed("group", true)
                .attr("rx",20)
                .attr("ry",20)
                .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); })
                .call(cola.drag);
            group.append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.bounds.x + d.bounds.width()/2})
                .attr("y", function(d) { return d.bounds.y + d.bounds.height()/2})
                .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

Comment: `var group = svg.selectAll(".group") .data(groups) .enter().append("g"); group.append("rect") .classed("group", true) .attr("rx",20) .attr("ry",20) .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); }) .call(cola.drag); group.append("text") .attr("x", function(d) { return d.bounds.x + d.bounds.width()/2}) .attr("y", function(d) { return d.bounds.y + d.bounds.height()/2}) .text(function(d) { return d.id; });` To be sure the text is appended to the `g` element. `group` === the selection with the `g` elements and not the `rects`

Comment: The labels show up but the rectangles bounding the nodes are now not showing!

Comment: `var group = svg.selectAll(".group") .data(groups) .enter().append("g") .classed("group", true); group.append("rect") .classed("grouprect", true) .attr("rx",20) .attr("ry",20) .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); }) .call(cola.drag); group.append("text") .classed("grouptext", true) .attr("x", function(d) { return d.bounds.x + d.bounds.width()/2}) .attr("y", function(d) { return d.bounds.y + d.bounds.height()/2}) .text(function(d) { return d.id; });` The `g` elements get the `group` class, the `rect` gets class `grouprect` and `text` gets class `grouptext`

Comment: Interestingly now both labels and rectangles are not showing up

Comment: Do i need to define a new var groupRect as well?

Comment: Did anyone ever get this working? A Plunk would be hextreemely lpful and gratefully appreciated. I just discovered webcola, thought it was the answer to my prayers and am now cursing it's lack of documentation. It may be time to move on ...